# updated AIR SDK from 23 to 25 and i get error Error: Unable to access jarfile /../lib/mxmlc-cli.jar

Tags: sdk, air

I have just updated my AIR SDK from version 23 to 25.
When running the command `mxmlc`, the following error occurs:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile /../lib/mxmlc-cli.jar

Comment: Which operating system? Windows?

Comment: im on mac OS :)

Comment: Please see my answer. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: trying the AIR SDK without the new compiler now, still downloading.

Comment: I'll be happy to know what the issue was...

Comment: ill post it here for sure for future reference :D

Comment: Yep, it worked, downloaded the SDK without the new compiler from here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html there's a note near the bottom of the page saying Note: Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without the new compiler. I'm not sure what's the difference though lol

Comment: Happy this worked for you. I'm gonna leave my answer as is, since there's no answer for this problem on SO and I still believe this is a real problem and a real solution, like I had. Have a great day !

Comment: BTW - You should **always** download the flex SDK, not the AIR SDK. It's a whole different compilre - I am updating my answer to write that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Make sure you have downloaded the **Flex SDK** and not the **AIR SDK**.
In the [download page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html), there's link specifying:

> Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without the new compiler.

---

### Solution 2:

When the Adobe AIR SDK is installed it is sometimes installing files with **wrong permissions**.

The `mxmlc-cli.jar` file your `lib` directory probably has a permissions issue.

Try giving this file full permission and making sure it's not read only and everything should work fine.

If you are using **Windows**, just right click the files and set up the proper permissions in the security tab, and make sure the file is not read only.

If you are using **Unix / Linux**, run the following:

```
$ su -
# cd [AIRSDK install directory]
# chmod -R go+rx *
```

If you are using **Mac OS**:

- Click the `mxmlc-cli.jar` file or to select it.
- From the File menu, select Get Info. One of the windows shown below
  appears. Click the disclosure triangle next to Sharing & Permissions
  to display the file's permissions.
- Click the lock and authenticate with an administrator account. Use
  the menus next to users and groups to change the permissions.

Comment: Please try setting the permissions on the entire lib directory

Comment: I had this problem a week ago and this solved it. Are you sure you've given the right permissions? Also try closing and opening the IDE

Comment: i also tried setting permissions for the sdk folder, same error :/ i'm not using any IDE, i compile everything on the Terminal.

Comment: Which permissions did you set exactly? To which users ?

Comment: Read & Write for all, for both lib folder and parent sdk folder

Comment: Can you double check the permissions on the `,jar` file? I am pretty much sure this is the problem. If the permissions are read write for everybody, I will delete my answer.

Comment: yep, its read & write for everyone :/ no need to delete your answer, it could be helpful for others. i will try AIR SDK without the new compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but I've faced this problem several times and the fix is really minor.

You have to edit `mxmlc` or `compile`.

In the file there is a row which should be changed to:

```
SCRIPT_HOME=`dirname "$0"`
```

The error comes from missing `" "` around the `$0`.